# Is there a way to reverse the order of lines within a text file using a function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop, reverse

```
def encrypt():
  while True:
    try:
        userinp = input("Please enter the name of a file: ")
        file = open(f"{userinp}.txt", "r")
        break  
    except:
      print("That File Does Not Exist!")
  second = open("encoded.txt", "w")
  
  
  for line in file:
    reverse_word(line)




def reverse_word(line):
  data = line.read()
  data_1 = data[::-1]
  print(data_1)
  return data_1

encrypt()
```

I'm currently supposed to make a program that encrypts a text file in some way, and one method that I'm trying to use is reversing the sequence of the lines in the text file. All of my other functions already made, utilize the "for line in file", where "line" is carried over to each separate function, then changed for the purpose of encryption, but when trying to do the same thing here for reversing the order of the lines in the file, I get an error

"str" object has no attribute "read"

I've tried using the same sequence as I did down below, but instead carrying over the file, which works, but I want to have it so that it can work when I carry over individual lines from the file, as is, with the other functions that I have currently (or more simply put, having this function inside of the for loop).

Any Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `sorted(open(path, 'r').readlines(), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the bug you're referring to is in this function:

```
def reverse_word(line):
  data = line.read()
  data_1 = data[::-1]
  print(data_1)
  return data_1
```

You don't need to call `read()` on `line` because it's already a string; `read()` is called on file objects in order to turn them into strings.  Just do:

```
def reverse_line(line):
    return line[::-1]
```

and it will reverse the entire line.

If you wanted to reverse the individual words in the line, while keeping them in the same order within the line (e.g. turn "the cat sat on a hat" to "eht tac tas no a tah"), that'd be something like:

```
def reverse_words(line):
    return ' '.join(word[::-1] for word in line.split())
```

If you wanted to reverse the order of the words but not the words themselves (e.g. turn "the cat sat on a hat" to "hat a on sat cat the"), that would be:

```
def reverse_word_order(line):
    return ' '.join(line.split()[::-1])
```

Comment: Yeah the first one you wrote is the one I needed, but It turns out when I write the function name under the for loop,  the program returns "_TextIOWrapper" object is not subscriptable. Any idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Sounds like you put a `[]` somewhere it doesn't belong.  Or you got confused about the difference between files and strings again, but this time in the opposite direction.

Comment: Oh wait it does work, but it's just that the error pops up when I try and write it to the file. I'm writing the whole function to the file as it seems to work when I use it on one of my other decrypting functions, are there any other ways that this can be done? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what "write the whole function to the file" means; there isn't any code in your original post that tries to write *anything* to the `second` file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to reverse the order of the lines or the order of the words in each line?

Reversing the lines can be done by simply reading the lines and using the built-in `reverse` function:

```
lines = fp.readlines()
lines.reverse()
```

If you're trying to reverse the words (actual words, not just the string of characters in each line) you're going to need to do some regex to match on word boundaries.

Otherwise, simply reversing each line can be done like:

```
lines = fp.readlines()
for line in lines:
    chars = list(line)
    chars.reverse()
```

Comment: For the reverse by character approach, the simpler solution is to just do `line = line[::-1]` rather than converting to `list` just to call `.reverse()` on it.